# How do you hide/unhide the tab bar when pushing/popping

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a tab bar which I only need on five screens. However, it goes to every screen when I push the view controller. How do I stop this from happening. I found a lot of solutions telling me to use hidesBottomBarWhenPushed but the problem I'm having with that is when I pop the view controller the tab bar is gone. How do I solve this problem? Also, please give me suggestions on my questions as I'm sort of new here! Thanks!

Edit: I've also seen this: self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = false, but this kind of looks odd as the tab bar just disappears in the middle of the push animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out. Basically in your viewdidAppear you add in self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true and in your viewDidDisappear you add in
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false. Thanks for your guys's answers anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Need to inherit UINavigationController custom navigation controller, override pushViewController & setViewControllers method to set hidesBottomBarWhenPushed, and then use custom navigation controller to jump

```
open class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {

  ...

  open override func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    if viewControllers.count > 0 {
      viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    }
    super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
  }

  open override func setViewControllers(_ viewControllers: [UIViewController], animated: Bool) {
    if viewControllers.count > 1, let vc = viewControllers.last {
      vc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    }
    super.setViewControllers(viewControllers, animated: animated)
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I found an easier solution